# MEF for Portable Library Class targeting .NET4.5, SL and Windows Store apps

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, mef, portable-class-library

I'm using a portable library class and I'm targeting to .NET 4.5, Silverlight 5 and Windows Store apps.

According to MSDN, it's possible to use MEF in these three plattforms: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx

But I can't accomplished to use MEF in these plattforms. What is the correct way to use MEF in PCL?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is incorrect. MEF was originally available in the box for Store apps, but due to a variety of reasons it was pulled before RTM. Currently, we have a newer version of MEF available between .NET 4.5 and Store apps (https://nuget.org/packages/microsoft.composition) but not between Silverlight, .NET and Store apps.

It's something we're considering for a future version. If you feel its important, can you file a suggestion over on uservoice: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/category/31481-net. Customer feedback/requests are weighted heavily when determining what we work on next.